# How to pass both event and parameters to a react function?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, kendo-grid, kendo-react-ui

I'm trying to pass both arguments and event to an external function in React.

If I invoke it this way,

```
 cell={ function (e){
                return CellWithEditing(x,y,z)
              }
```

It cannot find "this" and says props of undefined. As this is an external function I cannot even bind this.

This code works without the event -

```
 <GridColumn
          title="Manage"
          width="190px"
          minResizableWidth={170}
          cell={ CellWithEditing(
              this.props.config.title,
              this.props.manageGrid.edit,
              this.props.manageGrid.remove,
              this.props.manageGrid.addUsers,
              this.props.permission
            );
          }
          sortable={false}
          filterCell={this.emptyCell}
        />
```

The function outside the default class being called -

```
function CellWithEditing(x, y, event) {
  return class extends GridCell {
    constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.core = this.props.args;
    }

    render() {
      return (
       <h1>Sample Data</h1>
      );
    }
  };
}
```

This code does not work, when I use arrow function -

```
 <GridColumn
          title="Manage"
          width="190px"
          minResizableWidth={170}
          cell={ 
              (e)=>{
              CellWithEditing(
              this.props.config.title,
              this.props.manageGrid.edit,
              e)
             }
        }
          sortable={false}
          filterCell={this.emptyCell}
     />
```

I expect the function to be returned along with the event data.

Comment: Try adding `return` as `cell={ (e)=>{ return CellWithEditing()}`.

Comment: @ravibagul91 Yes I tried that. But it thows "Functions are not valid as a React child" error.

Comment: What happens when you try using the last approach? Are you getting any error?

Comment: That function returns  a *class*. You need an instance though, something like: `cell={<GridCell x="1" y="2" />}`

Comment: Because your are returning a function only - `return class extends GridCell`, try to return simple data.